# Executing a Ping Task in Android Java

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, ping, runtime.exec

I'm trying to implement a Ping utility as an AsyncTask in Android. The following is basically my `doInBackground` function.

```
mProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/ping -c 6 " + url );
    try {
        InputStream in = mProcess.getInputStream();
        OutputStream out = mProcess.getOutputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[ 1024 ];
        int count;

        while( ( count = in.read( buffer ) ) != -1 ){
            mPOut.write( buffer, 0, count );
            publishProgress();
            Log.d("PING TASK", "PING.... PING....");
            if( isCancelled() ) {
                return null;
            }
        }

        out.close();
        in.close();
        mPOut.close();
        mPIn.close();
    } finally {
        mProcess.destroy();
        mProcess = null;
        Log.d("PING TASK", "DONE");
    }
} catch( IOException e ) {
    Log.d("PING TASK", e.getMessage());
}
return null;
```

It works as intended, but only if I ping an address which responds, like `android.com` or `8.8.8.8`. But not if I ping an address which doesn't respond, like `intel.com` or `lalalalalalalaandroid.com` (I haven't exactly checked that one).

If I execute a `ping -c 6 intel.com` on my PC I do get at least the first Line `PING intel.com (13.91.95.74) 56(84) bytes of data.` Or `Ping request could not find host lalalalalalalaandroid.com Please check the name and try again.`.

But I don't get these in my Application... anything I'm missing here?

Comment: Note that there is no requirement for an Android device to have a `ping` utility, let alone at that specific filesystem location.

Comment: I know, this is not a Problem at the moment. I'm kinda just fiddling around.

Comment: what do you get if you run the command via `adb shell` instead of your PC (which is likely to run a different ping implementation)?

Answer (score 0):

As per the docs, AsyncTasks can only be executed once. Try reinitializing it in your timer runnable.

```
public void InitializeTimerTask() {
    timerPingTask = new timerPingTask() {
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    new PingAsyncTask().execute();
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's taken care of in the Activity's code.
Executing the Task multiple Times works.